# The point of using useCallback and useMemo in custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I have a simple custom hook that returns some functions:

```
const useCustom = () => {
   const someReduxValue = useSelector(...);

   const fn1 = useCallback(() => { 
     // do something with someReduxValue
   }, [...]);

   const fn2 = useCallback(() => { 
     // may include some complex operations like reducing/mapping etc
   }, [...]);

   return useMemo(() => ({
      fn1,
      fn2,
   }), [...]);
};
```

My question: is there any advantage in wrapping each functions (`fn1, fn2`) into `useCallbacks` and then wrapping all what hook returns into `useMemo`?

**Note**: no state used in this hook.

Comment: Will you ever check the result of your hook for referential equality? Do you want to use the result of your hook directly in a place where referential equality is important (e.g. directly as dependency of anothter hook or a a property of a component)? If so, it can make sense to "memo" it the way you do.

Comment: If your hook doesn't wrap state, doesn't accept arguments, and just returns a set of functions, then why did you write a hook at all? Instead, create a module that simply exports the two functions.

Comment: There is no point in using `useMemo` for your functions, because the whole point of `useCallback` is to guarantee a stable function instance as long as the dependecies are unchanged. Belts and suspenders.

Comment: @Bergi forgot to mention that Im using selectors in this hook

Comment: @underfrankenwood Ah, that makes more sense. So the functions are closures over `someReduxValue`?

Comment: @Martin The `useMemo` additionally ensures that the identity of the returned object doesn't change. This might be unnecessary (as it's usually just destructured right away), but still.

Comment: @Bergi so these functions are doing something with that redux value and returning stuff (if only it does make sense)

Comment: @Bergi any other thoughts Bergi?

Comment: other than what @nil already said, no.

Comment: Do you use return object value or any of that callbacks in it as a dependency for another `useCallcbsvl`/`useMemo`/`useEffect`?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your function.

`useMemo` and `useCallback` must be used carefully Because it fills the memory!

`useMemo` Returns a memoized value.
For example:
you have a function for checking that number is prime or not?
this function examin number 9851812358!
this is a big number for checking that and suppose in every rerender this function check this huge number for prime number!!!

`useMemo` memoized this value (is prime or not) and in re-rendering just returns last result and doesn't calculate this number again and again.

`useMemo` memoized value but `useCallback` returns a memoized callback!

Reactjs Docs:

> will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if
> one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing
> callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference
> equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

now. you should decide your function needs useMemo and useCallback or not!